# PDO Update Error: Invalid Parameter number - Parameter was not defined

Tags: php, pdo, parameters

I have read all the topics on this error:

> **exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined**

but can't seem to find where I went wrong.

**My code:**

```
$pdo->executePrepared([
        "query"=> "UPDATE users SET studie = :studie, studieland = :studieland, typestudie = :typestudie,
                   jaaropleiding = :jaaropleiding, onderwijsinstelling = :onderwijsintelling,
                   biografie = :biografie, voornaam = :voornaam, achternaam = :achternaam,
                   geslacht = :geslacht, geboortedatum = :geboortedatum WHERE userid = :userid LIMIT 1",
        "params"=>[
            ":studie"=> addslashes($studie_correct),
            ":studieland"=> $_POST['studieland'],
            ":typestudie"=> $typestudie,
            ":jaaropleiding"=> $_POST['jaaropleiding'],
            ":onderwijsinstelling"=>addslashes($_POST['onderwijsinstelling']),
            ":biografie"=> addslashes($_POST['biografie']),
            ":voornaam"=> addslashes($_POST['voornaam']),
            ":achternaam"=> addslashes($_POST['achternaam']),
            ":geslacht"=> $_POST['geslacht'],
            ":geboortedatum"=> $_POST['geboortedatum'],
            ":userid"=> $userid
        ]
    ]);
```

All of the parameters have a value so they are all defined.

I have done a lot of these kind of statements and they all went just fine, but I can't figure out what is wrong here.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Post your complete code including your database connection

Comment: Are you sure all of those variables are set? Maybe you're sending some NULL value and that's considered as a non sent parameter?

Comment: yes I'm sure, I track everything in the logs and they are all filled.

Answer (score 0):

I take you are using `Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql`? Just remove the `":"` in the array keys. Remove them only from the parameters array, not from the query string.

```
$pdo->executePrepared([
        "query"=> "UPDATE users SET studie = :studie, studieland = :studieland, typestudie = :typestudie,
                   jaaropleiding = :jaaropleiding, onderwijsinstelling = :onderwijsintelling,
                   biografie = :biografie, voornaam = :voornaam, achternaam = :achternaam,
                   geslacht = :geslacht, geboortedatum = :geboortedatum WHERE userid = :userid LIMIT 1",
        "params"=>[
            "studie"=> addslashes($studie_correct),
            "studieland"=> $_POST['studieland'],
            "typestudie"=> $typestudie,
            "jaaropleiding"=> $_POST['jaaropleiding'],
            "onderwijsinstelling"=>addslashes($_POST['onderwijsinstelling']),
            "biografie"=> addslashes($_POST['biografie']),
            "voornaam"=> addslashes($_POST['voornaam']),
            "achternaam"=> addslashes($_POST['achternaam']),
            "geslacht"=> $_POST['geslacht'],
            "geboortedatum"=> $_POST['geboortedatum'],
            "userid"=> $userid
```

Documentation on Phalcon PDO: https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql.html

Comment: I have no idea. I'm working in someone elses project and all the queries used need to be rewritten to these executePrepareds. But as I mentioned in my original post I have already done lots of them with the ":" in the keys and they worked fine.

Comment: Try without the ':' and let me know... It is tricky because `execute` uses the ':' but Phalcon's `executePrepared`  do not.

Comment: Why don't you try using `prepare` and then `executePrepared` just the way they use it in the documentation example here: https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql.html?